# proof a property of a linear differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I am supposed to proof that if a map $A:I \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\text{nxn}}$ where $I$ is a compact interval is continuous and A satisfies $\forall x \in \mathbb{C}^{\text{nxn}}: Re\langle Ax,x \rangle \le 0$, then we always have for $y'(t)=A(t)y(t)$ that for an arbitrary  $t_0 \in I: ||y(t)|| \le ||y(t_0)||$. Still, I do not know how to use this identity with the real part there. What is this telling me about the matrix, that is interesting to notice. I am not looking for a complete proof, just a hint at what this identity might be good for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint #1: squared norm is easier to work with, because it can be written as inner product.

Hint #2: product rule works (why?) for $\frac{d}{dt}\langle y(t),y(t)\rangle$.